# Strange cbrt() result on linux in C

Tags: c, linux, double

Why these two return value of the [cbrt()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cbrt.3.html) function are different ?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double nb = 56623104;
    double v1 = cbrt(nb);
    printf("v1 -> %.15f\n",v1);

    double v2 = cbrt((double) 56623104);
    printf("v2 -> %.15f\n",v2);
}
```

Compilation :

> gcc toto.c -o toto -lm && ./toto

Result :

> v1 -> 384.000000000000057
>   v2 -> 384.000000000000000

Comment: Put libraries (`-lm`) after source or object files (`toto.c`) for reliability.  What happens if you omit the `-lm` option?  It should fail to link, but...Have you looked at the assembler?  Does the compiler evaluate one of the function calls and leave the other to be evaluated at runtime?

Comment: If you use any opt level (01, O2, O3 or Ofast) result will be the same. I have dissasembled it and I see why it does it. Now I'm trying to explain why compiler does so ⊙﹏☉

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour with `#undef cbrt` ?

Comment: Trying this on clang 7.0.1, you do in fact get the right behavior. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NDoIwEAbvPMUGY1ISIbYKF5Un8dIfCk3KYqBwMb66tYZorHucyTcrc2k5tt5vDEo7qwbOk1NmKLo6iZA1ImY9d92bJAYd9NwgyeCeQDg1zMI2gAIuUFYVO9D98fRrFhqMFKMjKLLV3MaQ0SQNKq9hW9BSXzHdLTT4aMo@U7KS7Pviv8TiEgv@4f1Tasvbyee2fwE "C (clang) – Try It Online"). Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, this is a compiler bug.  The compiler is optimizing your code by evaluating one of the `cbrt` calls ahead of time, unfortunately, the compiler's version of `cbrt` is different from your version in libm.  You will also notice that passing `-O2` causes the `v2` result to be "wrong" as well (even though it's right, mathematically).

I verified that the bug exists on my system

> cc (Debian 6.3.0-5) 6.3.0 20170124

This bug should be reported to the compiler developers (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/), but it's a good idea to search the bug repository first.

Comment: I confirm the same behavior, including the effect of optimization, on CentOS 7.3 (cc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)).  I furthermore found that `-fexcess-precision=standard` does not affect the results.

Comment: As of GCC 10.2, this is still not fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/PPvfc6

Comment: I think this is actually a long-standing issue, and there is a well-known bug for it, but I don't know where it is.